# tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5

Tags: errors, texlive, updating

When I am trying to update TeX Live I receive an error.  Why does this happen and what does the error mean?

```
$ tlmgr update --self --all

/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

Comment: hi Henri! this also happens to me with the default repository `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet`. I don't have `tlcontrib`.
Do you have any suggestion, or it is better to open another question?

Comment: No, you don't have to ask a separate question because the answer remains the same.  The return value `-5` means that the key is expired.  Furthermore you've already go an answer from Norbert on the TeX Live list: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-April/045307.html

Comment: thanks Henri! I've seen that. Norbert has been lightning fast!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The return value of `-5` means that signature verification for a repository has failed.  There is currently a bug in `tlmgr` that prevents a sensible error message from being printed, but this is being worked on and should be fixed soon:

> https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-February/044775.html

The most recent incarnation of this problem stems from the fact that the signing key for the [`tlcontrib`](https://contrib.texlive.info/) repository expired.  You can check whether you have `tlcontrib` enabled by using

```
$ tlmgr repository list
List of repositories (with tags if set):
    http://contrib.texlive.info/current (tlcontrib)
    http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (main)
```

The maintainer of `tlcontrib` (Norbert Preining) has set his PGP key to expire every year, such that if the key were compromised it would become useless eventually.  To update to the latest key, just execute the key import that you also executed when you first installed `tlcontrib` again:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://www.preining.info/rsa.asc | tlmgr key add -
```

Comment: I tried that, and it says the key was imported, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Instead of using the output of `tlmgr repository list` to manually search for expired keys, the output of `tlmgr key list` can be used which directly provides the expiration time.

Comment: In my case, it was the main repository that had an expired key. To update that, import the following key as above: https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/texlive.asc

Answer (score 23):

In case the issue is not due to `tlcontrib`, running `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` solves the problem.
Kudos to Norbert Preining for the [answer on the TeX Live list](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-April/045307.html)!
I record here the required steps for posterity.

In case you don't have it, retrieve the script:

```
wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
```

Check if you can run `kpsewhich` from `sudo`:

```
sudo kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT
```

If yes, go to the last step. If not, check that the TeXLive path is in your `PATH`

```
echo $PATH
```

If not, add it with

```
 PATH="/path/to//texlive/:$PATH"
```

Finally, run the script (make it executable with `chmod +x`)

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" ./update-tlmgr-latest.sh
```

The `env` option passes to sudo the `PATH` already available to the user, without the need to change the `PATH` of the root user.
The output should look like

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: updating in /usr/local/texlive/2019...
./runme.sh: tlmgr version says this is TeX Live 2019,
./runme.sh: and this updater script created: Mon Apr  6 15:37:42 CEST 2020.
./runme.sh: proceeding with tlmgr update.
./runme.sh: updating /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux ...
./runme.sh: /opt/texbin/tlmgr including objects: master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.tlpobj master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-linux.tlpobj
D:appending to package log file: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
D:tlmgr:main: ::tldownload_server hash:: {enabled:1,errorcount:0,initcount:0,initcout:1,ua:LWP::UserAgent=HASH(0x564b37fdb010)}
D:setup_programs: preferring system versions
D:program curl found in path
D:program wget found in path
D:program lz4 not usable from path
D:(unix) trying to set up lz4, default /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/installer/lz4/lz4.x86_64-linux, arg --version
D: Using shipped /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/installer/lz4/lz4.x86_64-linux for lz4 (tested).
D:program gzip found in path
D:program xz found in path
./runme.sh: done.
```

Comment: Thanks! So the OP has installed texlive as root and you provide steps accordingly, but for a home install, I checked without `sudo` and the installer finds the correct  location.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong indeed. If `latex` and the other executables are in `/usr/local/texlive/...` sudo is possibly required. If they are in `/home/user/...`, `sudo` is most likely not required. Is this what you are saying, aren't you?

Comment: yes. I was just a bit puzzled by the inner workings of this updater script.

Comment: For brew users no kpsewhich nor sudo needed, just download the script and execute it. Thanks!

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04 (texlive 2019) which path should this be? I have /usr/share/texlive for example .

Comment: I'm with fomin; this fails on Ubuntu 20.04, even though /usr/share/texlive is in the user path and passed to sudo via env

Comment: How do I know whether the `kpsewhich` command worked? Mine prints `/`, which is not the directory where tex is installed. Does that mean it failed?

Comment: Agree. Fails on Ubuntu 20.04 even though /usr/share/texlive is in $PATH. kpsewhich returns /

Comment: Do you have a secure source for that script?  Downloading 8MB of code over insecure HTTP isn't very reassuring.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, I have the same texlive-path as @fomin and get the error `Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.` The output of this command is `/`. Is my installation messed up? I have texlive auto-installed.

Comment: Please change that URL to HTTPS; it's not safe to download executables over HTTP

Answer (score 8):

While still waiting for an official fix, the quickest way to get around this issue is to disable verification of downloads using the `verify-repo` argument.

Example:

```
tlmgr install lm-math --verify-repo=none
```

I can confirm that this works with texlive 2019 under Ubuntu 20.04.

**Note**: Default texlive version on Ubuntu 20.04 is 2019. Either you should (manually) upgrade to 2020, or make sure your repository is 2019, and not the CTAN default which is 2020.

[Here](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final) is an official 2019 repository, and you can add it by:

```
tlmgr option repository http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
```

Comment: You can't update TeX Live 2019 anyway, because it has been frozen, so I don't see the point of this.

Comment: No you can't update texlive 2019-- that line is just an example. But you can get past the annoying error that way and install packages if you have a 2019 repository.

Answer (score 2):

Alessandro's response is excellent, but it's also worth noting that it's recommended to default to your (already installed) TeXLive directory in bash

```
cd /usr/local/texlive/2021
```

before running the `wget` call (although I found that I had to run `sudo wget` for it to work). This will download the shell file straight into the directory. I found that not doing this and then manually copying the file into the directoty resulted in the `sudo kpsewhich` call returning an orphaned `/`, which was very frustrating to solve!

Also, after running

```
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH"
```

it may also be useful to run `sudo visudo` so that you can add that same path to the front of the 'secure_path' line, then `Ctrl+X` to save.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!