# tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5 for main repository

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

When I try to install a package using tlmgr, e.g.:

```
$ tlmgr install adjustbox
```

All I get is `/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5`.

In [tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528634/tlmgr-unexpected-return-value-from-verify-checksum-5) this error is caused by an out-of-date GPG key for `tlcontrib`, but I only have the `main` repository according to `tlmgr repository list`. I also tried re-downloading the key from CTAN and adding it, but that didn't work.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 and TeX Live 2019.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-April/045230.html and the follow-ups https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-April/045235.html and https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-April/045237.html on the TeX live mailing list.

Comment: Thank you! I just disabled verification and now it works...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For anyone encountering the same problem, the keys of the main TeX Live 2019 repo have also expired as of today (April 7, 2020). The verification check can be skipped using the `--verify-repo=none` option of `tlmgr`, just like this:

```
tlmgr --verify-repo=none install adjustbox
```