# How to make standalone package available by my LaTeX installation?

Tags: packages, installing, standalone, ubuntu, tlmgr

I want to use LaTeX notes in Xournal++ on Ubuntu to annotate on .pdf.
However when I click on insert a LaTeX formula, I got:

> Could not find LaTeX package 'standalone'. Please install standalone (found in texlive-latex-extra) and make sure it's accessible by your LaTeX installation).

[image]

I went online to search for help and tried:

[sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100929/how-to-install-latex-package-called-standalone-properly-so-i-can-get-update-wi)

which gave:

> texlive-latex-extra is already the newest version (2019.202000218-1).
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 211 not upgraded.

I tried a tlmgr install with:

> $ tlmgr install standalone
> (running on Debian, switching to user
> mode!)
>
> /usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5

I finally went [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537376/tlmgr-unexpected-return-value-from-verify-checksum-5-for-main-repository) because of the unexpected return value:

> tlmgr --verify-repo=none install standalone (running on Debian,
> switching to user mode!)
>
> tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
> Cross release updates are only supported with
> update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update See
> https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.

Are there other steps I am missing or am I doing it completely wrongly?

Comment: If you are using LaTeX from Ubuntu you cannot use `tlmgr` to install latex packages, Ubuntu wants you to get LaTeX packages via Ubuntu bundles. Are you sure you don't by an strange reason have more than one LaTeX installation? Such that `Xournal++` (which I've never heard of) sees the wrong latex. For example in a terminal what does `kpsewhich standalone.sty` give?

Comment: @daleif, thanks for your comment. Didn't know for tlmgr. Here's the output `$ kpsewhich standalone.sty`

`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.sty
`
Does it mean I have one LaTeX installation?

Comment: That means that when you use the terminal then the `standalone` package is available. Are there any logs from `Xournal++` where one can see what it is doing? And what happens if you start it via the terminal instead of via, say, a menu or double clicking.

Comment: @daleif, I didn't find any logs. Maybe because it's a GUI app. I found how to launch the GUI from terminal. When I then clicked on LaTeX Formulas I got : `kpsewhich: /etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf: Permission denied
`
From there, I told myself, maybe it needed `sudo xournalpp` but this command says : `kpsewhich: /etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf: Permission denied
`. Sorry we are walking a little away from TeX!

Comment: That sounds more like you have a very strange setup. Sorry cannot help you more.

Comment: @daleif `sudo xournalpp` gives `mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
` I miss paste.
Thanks anyway, maybe I'll manage to find out or someone else will know :)

Comment: in any case your problem is not with the tex installation (standalone is installed)

Comment: You should never need to run `xournalpp` as root.

Comment: I just tried installing it on Ubuntu 18.04 using Upstream LaTeX (nit LaTeX from Ubuntu), seems to work fine when I run it from the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, it is not exactly a fixing way but at least it worked. I uninstalled Xournal++ with Ubuntu software.

I then reinstalled it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/xournalpp-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

As suggested in the [GitHub Readme](http://sudo%20add-apt-repository%20ppa:apandada1/xournalpp-stable%20sudo%20apt%20update%20sudo%20apt%20install%20xournalpp).
And now the LaTeX Formulas work. The version of xournalpp in Ubuntu's software center is a sandboxed snap package, and it has incompatibility issues with external components like LaTeX. Installing the native Debian package (in the PPA) solves the problem.

I also now understand it's not that much a LaTeX related question.

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you using? I did not find it in my Ubuntu 18.04 and thus used the same approach

Comment: @daleif, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04