# /usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, update

I recently updated from Ubuntu 19.04 to Ubuntu 19.10 and it seems that I have lost a number of Latex packages, including colophon and enumitem.  TeXLive came bundle with Ubuntu but I reinstalled it from the download at the TeXLive website.

When I try to run `tlmgr install enumitem` it gives me the above error.  I tried doing what had been suggested in a similar post and using --verify-repo=none.  However, it then says

```
tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

so I tried running update-tlmgr-latest.sh.  But it says Command not found even though I have downloaded the file and it's definitely there. Then I tried uninstalling and reinstalling TeXLive using the instructions on the website.  I did this twice, and each time it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install TeX live? If you installed TeX live via `apt`/`apt-get` from the Ubuntu repositories it is my understanding that you should not be using `tlmgr` to update or install packages. On Debian systems, TeX packages are spread across different collections that you can install via `apt`/`apt-get` (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=texlive).

Comment: Is this helpful? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537810/177