# How to get nicematrix to work in texlive 2019

Tags: texlive-2019, nicematrix

I am using `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`.  My simple test code is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}c!{\qquad}ccc!{\qquad}ccc@{}}
    \toprule
    & \Block{1-3}{First group} & & & \Block{1-3}{Second group} \\
    Rank & 1A & 1B & 1C & 2A & 2B & 2C \\
    \midrule
    1 & 0.657 & 0.913 & 0.733 & 0.830 & 0.387 & 0.893\\
    2 & 0.343 & 0.537 & 0.655 & 0.690 & 0.471 & 0.333\\
    3 & 0.783 & 0.885 & 0.015 & 0.306 & 0.643 & 0.263\\
    4 & 0.161 & 0.708 & 0.386 & 0.257 & 0.074 & 0.336\\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

This gives me:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment NiceTabular undefined.
```

The version of nicematrix is `2020/02/07 v3.11`

Is there any way to use nicematrix  with Tex Live 2019?

Comment: `nicematrix` expects latest version of `latex3` supporting files, better to update your package manager and then try...

Comment: @MadyYuvi This is the latest version that ubuntu 20.04 gives you and that is the latest version of ubuntu.

Comment: `NiceTabular` is a rather new environment added in `nicematrix` `2020/05/08 v4.0`, see the corresponding [announcement text](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.520.1589129970.3866.ctan-ann@ctan.org). You need to either use old environments or upgrade `nicematrix` or the whole latex distribution.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ what is the cleanest way to upgrade nicematrix without upgrading the whole latex distribution?

Comment: `Tex Live Package Manager`.

Comment: @fomin Manually installation. `nicematrix` consists of a single `nicematrix.sty` file which you can download from [texlive's svn repo](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty?limit_changes=0&view=log). If newer version of `nicematrix` relies on any new codes from its dependencies, the whole process will be much much harder.

Comment: Alternatively, you can follow the steps in https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html to upgrade from texlive 2019 to 2020 without a new installation.

Comment: @Bernard I just tried it. There seems to be a bug https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528634/tlmgr-unexpected-return-value-from-verify-checksum-5  which has suggested workarounds that I am trying to get to work.

Comment: I have put the file latest version of `nicematrix.sty` (5.1) here : (https://pastebin.pl/view/b9780ffe). It works with TeXLive 2019. You put that file in the reportory of your document and that's all.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thank you so much! The link doesn't seem to work though. It just hangs for me.

Comment: @fomin: Yes. There is a problem. If you want, send me a mail (fpantigny@wanadoo.fr). I will send you the file.

Comment: Just copying nicematrix.sty does seem to work. Thank you.