# Using package nicematrix with TexLive 2020

Tags: texlive, nicematrix

I have a document in which I load nicematrix and tikz, and I can compile it without error using TexLive 2022. The compilation fails, however, when I try to submit to the Arxiv where they use TexLive 2020. I include the nicematrix.sty file with my submission.

The error message ends with:

```
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)

! Undefined control sequence.
l.73 \hook_gput_code:nnn
{ begindocument } { . }
?
! Emergency stop.
l.73 \hook_gput_code:nnn
{ begindocument } { . }
No pages of output.
Transcript written on A11_final.log.
```

I was getting the same \hook_gput_code:nnn error before I upgraded to TexLive 2022.

My google searches all come up with the solution "upgrade your tex" but this is not an option on the Arxiv.

Is there a work around that allows me to use nicematrix with TeXLive 2020?

As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558971/197451

Comment: I read through this thread before posting. Including nicemtrix.sty did not resolve the error in my case.

Comment: Maybe you would need to download an older nicematrix.sty file with the submission instead.

Comment: You can't imho use a current nicematrix with an older latex. If you prevent this error by defining the command you will get more from other commands. Try what happens if you don't include nicematrix in the submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm the author of `nicematrix`).

The last version of `nicematrix` compatible with TeXLive 2020 is the version 6.3 of 2021-10-18.

Maybe you don't use the most recent functionnalities of `nicematrix` and that version will be sufficient for your needs.

The different versions of the file `nicematrix.sty` can be downloaded on the SVN server of TeXLive [here](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty).

That link does not provide the corresponding documentation files. If you want the corresponding file (`nicematrix.pdf`, or in French `nicematrix-french.pdf`) send me a email (you will find may address on the first page of the documentation available on CTAN).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The compilation proceeded further, but now stops with

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \OverBrace

Perhaps the \OverBrace functionality was added after 6.3 of 2021-10-18?

Comment: Removing all \OverBrace lines results in successful compilation. I am sad to lose these however. Thank you again!