# tlmgr : Error with Texlive

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I use Xubuntu 20.04, Texstudio with Texlive.
I want to load and install new package with `tlmgr` in graphical user mode. When i push the button "load deposit by default", the window cut off and i can read in a terminal window :

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

Same answer with the command `tlmgr udate -all`

How to fix it ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: More informations about tlmgr :                                                                                               tlmgr revision 53568 (2020-01-27 19:20:16 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2019

Comment: Please add that information to your question not a comment. If that is the TexLive 2019 version, then it cannot be updated anymore.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528634/177 ?