# Compilation failing because 'fontawesome5.sty' is not found when using package 'fontawesome5

Tags: packages, compilation-error, fontawesome, fontawesome5

I am unable to use the package "fontawesome5" as my compilation fails with the following error:

> '! LaTeX Error: File `fontawesome5.sty' not found.'

The compilation runs fine on my Windows machine but I cannot get it working on Linux.

So far I have tried downloading the [fontawesome package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5?lang=en) and extracting its contents under the directory returned by running `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` (which I had to create). I then ran `texhash` on this directory.

This did not resolve my issue however.

FYI I am using `texlive-latex-extra`. Maybe `texlive-full` comes with the fontawesome package and I wouldn't have to worry about manually installing it?

But there has to be a simpler solution. How can I get my compiler to find this fontawesome5.sty file?

Comment: latex won't "find" it you need to install it. If you installed tex from tug, then `tlmgr install fontawesome5` would do it. if you use the linux packaged tex it depends on your distribution, you need to install a suitable collection via apt or whatever linux package manager you use

Comment: when I try to tug, i get `/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5`

Comment: Did you install texlive from your distro's repos, or from tug? If from your distro, then if on a Debian based system, like Ubuntu, try installing `texlive-fonts-extra`. If on an Arch-based system, try installing `texlive-fontsextra`. (I think it's also called `texlive-fontsextra` on RPM-based distros like Fedora.)

Comment: Check [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528634/tlmgr-unexpected-return-value-from-verify-checksum-5) about the verify_checksum error.